# How to convert binary, OCT, HEX to calculate in Java?

Tags: java

Write an application that inputs one number consisting of FIVE digits from the user, separates the number into its individual digits and prints the digits separated from one another by three spaces each. For example, if the user types in the number 12345, the program should print

```
1   2   3   4   5
```

The following screen dump of result is for your reference.

```
Input a digit: 12345
Digits in 12345 = 1 2 3 4 5
```

How to convert binary, OCT, HEX to calculate the question?

```
int digit1, digit2, digit3, digit4, digit5;
digit1 = number / 10000;
digit2 = number % 10000 / 1000;
digit3 = number % 1000 / 100;
digit4 = number % 100 / 10;
digit5 = number % 10;
```

Comment: please explain what you mean by 'How to convert binary, OCT, HEX to calculate the Question' - that has no relation to the rest of your post

Comment: Hi, welcome at Stackoverflow! For future homework/interview assignments, please tag `homework` as well. Oh, please also use one question mark `?` instead of a bunch of exclamation marks `!!!!!!!!!` to represent a question, otherwise it's been interpreted as yelling/jerking.

Comment: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100225072007AAjYacG

Comment: @Roman: [There are more as well...](http://google.com/search?q=%22Write+an+application+that+inputs+one+number+consisting+of+FIVE+digits+from+the+user%22)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the methods the [`java.lang.Integer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) class provides, such as `toBinaryString()`, `toOctalString()` and `toHexString()` and the `toString()` and `valueOf()` methods taking a `radix` (which is the *base*, e.g. binary is 2, octal is 8, etc).